# Importing data.table with rpy2 gives LoadLibrary failure: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, r, windows, data.table, rpy2

The error message includes:

`unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll'`

even though the dll exists in the said location.

Below is the output from sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.2 tools_4.1.2
```

I am using Python 3.10, rpy2 version 3.4.5, running in VSCode Jupyter notebook.

```
PS C:\Users\XXXXXX\GitHub\QT> pip show rpy2
Name: rpy2
Version: 3.4.5
Summary: Python interface to the R language (embedded R)
Home-page: https://rpy2.github.io
Author: Laurent Gautier
Author-email: lgautier@gmail.com
License: GPLv2+
Location: c:\users\013769\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
Requires: cffi, jinja2, pytz, tzlocal
Required-by:
PS C:\Users\XXXXXX\GitHub\QT>
```

I have added R to my environment variables PATH and i have installed and added rtools40 to my PATH as well.

Output of .libPaths() below as well:

```
import rpy2.robjects as r
libPaths = r.r('''
       .libPaths()
        ''')
print(libPaths)
```

```
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library"
```

Comment: As a potential workaround, have you able to use "datatable" in python? Re [Python datatable vs R data.table comparison](https://samukweku.github.io/data-wrangling/python_datatable_vs_R_datatable.html)

Comment: Have some fairly chunky R code working which I would like to call from Python for various reasons. If we end up porting across then we will likely just use pandas, but there should be no need thanks to interoperability with rpy2. Thanks for the suggestion though. It is a consideration.